# Simple Question: Work done by a spring in a mechanical vibration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, harmonic-oscillator, spring

[image: Graph of X0cos(w0t)]

The graph represents $x(t)$.

Its a simple question yet i seem to confuse the work done by the restoring force of the spring by other works/forces.

> My question is : What is the work done by the restoring force of this spring between t1 & t2 with t1 = 0, t2 = 1s
>
> With K = 12.5 N/m , m = 0.2Kg

Comment: You could find the expression for x(t) from the graph. From the graph you can find the frequency and the amplitude in these un-named units. Then you just calculate the work between these two point by integrating the usual formula for work

Comment: I seem to be really lost when it comes to the work formulas
if you could explain it more i'd appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to integrate, for this simple case.

At t2=1s the displacement is zero. This means that 
PE=0  and KE2 is at maximum value.

At t1=0, the displacement is maximum and velocity is zero so KE1=0.

According to the work-energy theorem, the work done is equal to the change in KE, in this case
W=KE2-KE1= KE2

But KE2 is the maximum KE so it also equal to the maximum PE which is reached at maximum dispacement.

So $ W=\frac{1}{2}  kA^2 $
k is given and A you can find from the graph if you know what units are used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you deleted your previous post for a question that was basically the same as this one, but my answer is still the same and is still correct: One is always able to apply the work-energy theorem, $W=\Delta K$. You're given enough information to determine the kinetic energy before (0, because the system starts at rest) and the kinetic energy at t=2t=2s. You then have $\Delta K$ and therefore $W$.

Comment: Thank you again for answering, i deleted the previous post cause i thought it was not comprehensible.
You see, i have another exercise that has the same question, by using the W(FR) formula on it = 1/2 KX2² - 1/2Kx1², the result found by them doesn't even equal the my result, thats why im still very confused :/